# How to downgrade python in pycharm from 3.8 to 3.7 (I'm trying to run Tensorflow)

Tags: python-3.x

Running into installation error in python 3.8 for tensorflow and i'm wondering how to downgrade without losing my environments in pycharm.

Comment: Simply download the version you want and update the interpreter in Pycharm's settings https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Download](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and install Python 3.7
2. In PyCharm, go to 'File' -> 'Settings' -> 'Project: <...>' -> 'Project Interpreter', and select 'Python 3.7' in the 'Project Interpreter' dropdown.
3. If you don't see it, click on the settings icon next to it, go
   to the 'System Interpreter' tab, and browse to and select
   'python.exe' from the **Python37** folder

Answer (score 3):

Step1 : **Go to Preferences:**

[image]

Step 2: Go to Python Interpreter

[image]

Step 3: click Show All

[image]

Step 4: Click on + button

[image]

Step 5: select the Version you have installed on your computer.

[image]

Step 6: Select the added environment and click ok

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: run following command on Terminal cse572 is the environment Name:

```
conda create -n cse572 python=3.7 scikit-learn=0.21.2 pandas=0.25.1
```

Step 2: `conda activate cse572`

Step 3: `python --version` should show python version 3.7